# Upgrade from 2.5.5 to latest EE2 update

Tags: v2.5.5

I am currently assessing all aspects for a complete refresh of our site and have seen that we are running EE2 2.5.5. I'm no developer but I do have to establish what steps we should take as the current CMS is restrictive, most certainly down to running a 2012 version...

What advice/warnings can anyone give me to take the best route forward?

Can we migrate all content to EE3 for instance, or is the best advice to go straight to a web design/builder and hand over the problem to them to resolve?

I apologise for such naive questions, but would appreciate any advice someone might be able to give me.

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 2):

The two priorities will be backing up the database/files and ensuring your server meets the requirements of the update.You will need a minimum of php 5.3.10 (though I would personally put 5.6 as the minimum). If you have php7 available on the server, go for that. Huge performance and security improvements.

As to whether you upgrade to the latest version of 2 or up to 3 (btw v.4 is on the horizon) will depend on whatever addons you have installed and if they support version 3. Do note that v2 has been discontinued, so EllisLab is no longer maintaining it.

If you have the ability to run the update in a staging or developer environment first, that's always helpful to find any problems before updating your production site.

Regarding your "current CMS is restrictive" comment, that's rather vague and impossible to comment on.